# Make files open with a certain app on Windows client machines

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

At work I am running Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit and all the clients are Windows 7 32-bit.

I would like all ISO files to open automatically with VLC player when double clicked. At the moment if I login as the administrator and change the default behaviour it works fine, but as soon as a new user logs in, it has to be reset once again (some PCs can have over a 100 users)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [creating and configuring a new **File Type Item** using **Group Policy**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754587.aspx):

> 1. Open the **Group Policy Management Console**. Right-click the Group Policy object (GPO) that should contain the new preference item, and
>      then click **Edit**.
> 2. In the console tree under **Computer Configuration**, expand the **Preferences** folder, and then expand the **Control Panel Settings** folder.
> 3. Right-click the **Folder Options** node, point to **New**, and select **File Type**.
> 4. In the **New File Type Properties** dialog box, select an **Action** (such as **Create**) for Group Policy to perform. (For more information, see "Actions" in the linked article.)
> 5. Enter file type settings (such as **File extension** and **Associated class**) for Group Policy to configure or remove. (For more information, see "File type settings" in the linked article.)
> 6. Click the **Common** tab, configure any options, and then type your comments in the **Description** box. (For more information, see
>      [Configure Common Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772371.aspx).)
> 7. Click **OK**. The new preference item appears in the details pane.

Comment: Hi almost done but!-- in the file extension box I have typed .iso but the associated class does bot have "vlc media file .iso" (plenty of other vlc file types) although vlc player happily plays ISO files

Comment: From the article: "You do *not* need to insert the period before the file name extension."

Comment: Sorry for long delay - Have tried with and without the period but the file type does not appear in the associated class (have tried a few random) but none work :(

Comment: Hi all any more help with this would be great :)

Comment: Did you press F3 to display the list as mentioned? Other than that unfortunately I'm all out of ideas as to why it's not working.

Comment: Hi got it in the end! I think I must have followed something wrong along the way! Thanks again